# inserted button is not visible. Constrained Layout

Tags: android-constraintlayout

When I drag and drop button in design mode. The button is not shown. why?

it is in top left corner. [image]

Comment: it can be a bug with android studio version 3.4.1

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the view has constraints set.

Otherwise, it behaves this way - AS even tells you.

> This view is not constrained. It only has designtime positions, so **it will jump to (0,0) at runtime**...